# How to downgrade php 5.5 to 5.4 on Ubuntu 13?

Tags: php5, ubuntu-13.04

I'm using kubuntu 13.04
I've used a downgrade script to downgrade php 5.4 to 5.3 earlier, and now I deleted the repo and that script, removed php 5.3 and now when installing again, it's installing php 5.5 not 5.4.

How do I install php 5.4 not 5.5 ?

Comment: Any other repos? Show your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any other files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: 13.04 has PHP 5.4 by default, so you must have some third-party repos active. Please post your sources lists as suggested by Pazi. Also, what script did you use?

Comment: Just a question: Why you are not fine with 5.5?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i wanted to post this as a comment but dont have enough rep. Anyway i had to do the same and followed [these steps](https://superuser.com/questions/662824/downgrade-php-from-5-5-3-to-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-13-10), below is the following i did to go back to PHP 5.4

remove your php, apache, etc

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 # add here your server packages
```

change repositories to raring  (with backup)

```
sudo sed -i.bak "s/saucy/raring/g" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

update and install server packages

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 phpmyadmin
```

change repositories back to saucy

```
sudo sed -i "s/raring/saucy/g" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

ignore all current upgrades (package hold)

```
sudo apt-mark hold `aptitude -F%p --disable-columns search ~U`
```

Comment: This looks like an answer rather than a comment, so there's no reason to apologize for not making it a comment.

Answer (score -2):

You could download the version you want from the PHP Git repository and compile it manually.

The compilation requirements are:

- autoconf: 2.13+ (for PHP < 5.4.0), 2.59+ (for PHP >= 5.4.0)
- automake: 1.4+
- libtool: 1.4.x+ (except 1.4.2)
- re2c: Version 0.13.4 or newer
- flex: Version 2.5.4 (for PHP <= 5.2)
- bison: Version 1.28 (preferred), 1.35, or 1.75

You can download the 5.4 snapshot as source code from [git.php.net: 5.4.22](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=bd4301120f24e4920c19d3ff0613a67c561a1d3f)

Here is a guide for installing from source: [install php5 from source on linux](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/07/instruction-guide-to-install-php5-from-source-on-linux/)

Article source: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.php).